# Rails + Devise - Authenticate method in custom controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

Is there an equivalent to the **Authenticate** method from RestfulAuthentication, like so?

```
@user = User.authenticate(@email, @password)
```

I have a custom controller i use for authenticating a mobile request, where the email/password come from the url, like **http://localhost:3000/iphone/auth/frexuz@frexuz.com/mypassword**

Comment: Definitely shouldn't have the password in the route!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
user = User.find(:first, :conditions => ["email = ?", @email])
user.valid_password?(@password) unless user.nil?
```

Comment: This is awesome, I need to go back and forth between devise and Rails 'has_secure_password', and user.valid_password?(a_password) is the equivalent to user.authenticate(a_password) when using 'has_secure_password' without devise. Thanks for the insight

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot! But can we find define current_user similar way?